# pairing android bluetooth with pc in code

Tags: android, bluetooth

I read Google documents about connecting devices with each other (PAIRING THEY SAY).
In Google they said that if two devices have same UUID they can connect and pair using 
 
BluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(name, uuid) method 
 
This method pairs two Bluetooth devices with same UUID but in my case I have a PC Server where it's UUID 0001 which is different and I use it for Streaming Message. 
My question is Can I pair my android phone with PC using codes and if answer is yes ,then How?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: For pairing one device(initiator) will provide a 4 digit code. This code needs to be entered in the second device for completion of pairing. You can send this in your android method, and when prompted on your pc you can enter same code to complete pairing. might want to have a look at the following link http://digitalhacksblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/android-example-bluetooth-simple-spp.html